# FadeIn a div from left to right

Tags: jquery, fadein

Is it possible to FadeIn a div from left to right, what I mean is that first the left part of the div will fadeIn and slowly to the right side. I already found a lot of questions like this but not the right one.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer slides the div to sight. I made another fiddle, using 2 divs and playing with transparency and gradient color to have more of an gradient fade effect. [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jq9b3x43/)

```
<div class="bottom"><div class="top"></div></div>

.bottom {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0;
}
.top {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, white, transparent);
    opacity: 1;
}

$(".bottom").animate({
    "opacity": "1"
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
$(".top").animate({
    "opacity": "0"
}, 500) }, 400 );
```

Comment: You're welcome. Adjust the timing on the animations if you see a glitch or a step between the. Made this in a bit of a hurry..

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no built-in conventional way to do this.

However, I did this in a makeshift way by making two simultaneous animations.

I first created a white cover element that completely covers the `<div>`. The `<div>` is initially set to `opacity: 0`. The cover slides over as the `<div>` becomes opaque.

Here are the animations:

**jQuery**

```
$("div#div").animate({
    "opacity": "1"
}, 500);
$("div#cover").animate({
    "left": "+=400px"
}, 500);
```

**CSS**

```
div#div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0;
}
div#cover {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div"></div>
<div id="cover"></div>
```

It's a bit hard-coded (not dynamic), but it's the closest I got in such a simple method (I'm sure there are more complex ways to do this).

See working example [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51ereygL/2/).